# how do I get the updated_at and created_at

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm making my first Larevel (4) application and I want to display the date that it was created and I'm getting this problem: `Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing`

when I try to do this in my blade template

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    <h3>Name: {{ $user->name }}</h3>
    <p>Email: {{ $user->email }}</p>
    <p>Bio: {{ $user->bio }}</p>
@endsection()
@section('sidebar')
  <p><small>{{ $user->created_at }}</small></p>
@endsection()
@stop
```

and my controller

```
<?php 
class UserController extends BaseController 
{
  public $restfull = true;

  public function get_index() {
    //$users = User::all();// gets them in the order of the database
    $users = User::orderBy("name")->get(); // gets alphabetic by name
    $v = View::make('users');
    $v->users = $users;
    $v->title = "list of users";
    return $v;
  }

  public function get_view($id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $v = View::make('user');
    $v->user = $user;
    $v->title = "Viewing " . $user->name;
    return $v;
  }

} 
?>
```

it works as soon as I take out :

```
<p><small>{{ $user->created_at }}</small></p>"
```

any ideas how to access those values, I checked and they DO exist in my table.

this is the schema of my table

`CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" integer null primary key autoincrement, "email" varchar null, "name" varchar null, "bio" varchar null, "created_at" datetime null, "updated_at" datetime null);`

Comment: Could you please post your raw SQL table structure?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" integer null primary key autoincrement, "email" varchar null, "name" varchar null, "bio" varchar null, "created_at" datetime null, "updated_at" datetime null);`

Comment: Are their values filled by seeding the database or you have entered them manually?

Comment: Why don't you try naming your view something different than "user". Maybe that is causing some name collision. Try changing $v = View::make('user'); into $v = View::make('displayuser');

Comment: They are manual in the migration 

` DB::table('users')->insert(
      array(
        'email' => 'something@mail.com',
        'name' => 'Elvis Person',
        'created_at' => date("Y-M-D H:m:s"),
        'updated_at' => date("Y-M-D H:m:s"),
        'bio' => "my stuff"
      )
    );`

Comment: If that is the case try using this  'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime and re-run the migration

Comment: @GladToHelp totally works! thanks so much. how would I make a auto way of doing DateTime? is that built in or is that something I still need to make?

Comment: See eloquent [timestamps](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#timestamps). Instead of inserting users in migrations use [seeding](http://four.laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding). And don't insert using `DB::table(..)->insert(..)`, use you models for that (see [eloquent insert](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete))

Comment: I was using table() so that solved my problem! thank so much!

Answer (score 2):

So here's what I did to fix it.

in the migrations I did this:

```
class CreateTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function($table) {
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

/* also need function down()*/
```

I had the insertions like this in my `migrations` to add some users.

```
  class AddRows extends Migration {

  /* BAD: this does NOT! update the timestamps */ 

  public function up()
  {
     DB::table('users')->insert( array('name' => 'Person') );
  }

  /* GOOD: this auto updates the timestamps  */ 
  public function up()
  {
      $user = new User;

      $user->name = "Jhon Doe";

      $user->save();
    }
  }
```

Now when you try to use `{{ $user->updated_at }}` or `{{ $user->created_at }}` it will work! (assuming that you passed $user to the view)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here that should probably be fixed.  Since this is a restful controller, Laravel expects your function names to be camelCase rather than snake_case.

The way you are passing variables to the view also is not looking right.  Try passing the `$users` variable to the view with `return View::make('users')->with('users',$users);`.

Another thing is you are passing a collection of users to the view, which means you won't just be able to echo user information.  To get the user information out of the collection, you must iterate through the collection with a loop.  (Your app will probably break again once you get more than one user in)

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
     echo $user->name;
     echo $user->email;
     echo $user->bio;
}
```

Because the way you have your sidebar and content sections showing user information, what you probably actually want to do to get your user is something along the lines of `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` meaning it would be returning one user and you'd be able to lose the loop.

One more thing I just seen.  If you are setting up a restful controller, the proper property is `public $restful = true;` though I'm not sure that's actually being used anymore because you are basically setting that in `routes.php` with `Route::controller('user', 'UserController');`.

Comment: the way I made the view actually does work it's just a different syntax. I didn't think that the restful thing was working... And I think the loop your looking at is for another view I which case I have a loop in the view.